# C++: Is it safe to cast from wchar_t* to unsigned short*?

Tags: c++, casting, saxparser

C++: Is it safe to cast from **wchar_t* to unsigned short***?

Because I am using the SAXReader of MSXML2 I need to pass unsigned short* some of its methods. The values I need to pass are wchar_t, so it is safe to do this cast?

Comment: In general, no.  Specifically, you *might* get away with it if `sizeof (wchar_t)` is equal to `sizeof (unsigned short)`, but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: Some systems define wchar_t as unsigned int.

Comment: @freim: That's illegal in C++. `wchar_t` is a distinct type. (As opposed to say `std::size_t`, which _can_ be a typedef for unsigned int.)

Comment: @MSalters - I was not clear enough, sorry. I wanted to say that on some systems wide char occupies 4 bytes. So casting wchar_t* to unsigned short* is not safe, even if such cast is allowed by the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general the cast is not safe since *strict aliasing* rules forbid it.

But you would get away with it if `wchar_t` is a `typedef` for `unsigned short`. If it is you could enforce that at compile time using a `static_assert`, based on the value of

```
std::is_same<whar_t, unsigned short>::value
```

Note further though that such an implementation is relying on your compiler not implementing the standard correctly: Formally `wchar_t` has the same size, signedness, and alignment as one of the integer types, but is a distinct type." Therefore a `typedef` would not be compliant and the value assertion should always fail.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: [cppreference says](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types): "[`wchar_t`] has the same size, signedness, and alignment as one of the integer types, but is a distinct type." -- so a typedef would not be compliant. MSVC does have exactly this option though, but I don't think I need to elaborate on that ;)

Comment: @Quentin: Nicked that comment and wiki'd the answer.

Comment: Strict aliasing rule does not forbid it at all, as here OP is attempting to access the memory location through a char pointer !

The standard is explicit [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Strict_aliasing), stating that there is no _undefined behavior_ if  T2 (type of the pointer though which `wchar_t` data is accessed) is a character type (char, signed char, or unsigned char).